# IComparable Sorting Month is not calling overridden Equal or CompareTo property

Tags: c#

I am writting code to take a datatable and return the data in sorted order by Month in accordance to their numerical month value.   When I run the code, the data is not sorted. In debug mode, I noticed that the ToString() method is called to return the MonthName however, the Equals(object obj) or CompareTo is never called. In another program, this code does work, but for my new module is not not working. Can anyone offer insight why the Equals method is not called to sort the data? Thanks.

```
// Populate class that implements IComparable for custom sorting on Month
        List<SortedMonth> lstPivot = new List<SortedMonth>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            lstPivot.Add(
                new SortedMonth
                {
                    MONTH = new Month
                    {
                        MonthName = row["MONTH"].ToString().Trim(),
                        MonthNumber = !row.IsNull("MONTH") ? DateTime.ParseExact(row["MONTH"].ToString().Trim(), "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month : 0
                    }
                });
        }

public class SortedMonth: IComparable
{


    public Month MONTH { get; set; }


    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

//[Serializable]
public class Month : IComparable
{

    public string MonthName { get; set; }
    public int MonthNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return MonthName;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Month month = obj as Month;
        if (month != null)
        {
            return MonthNumber.Equals(MonthNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return MonthNumber.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return MonthNumber.CompareTo(((Month)obj).MonthNumber);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's because you aren't calling them anywhere. Are you missing code here?

Answer (score 2):

A number of reasons:

- `List<T>` does not automatically maintain your elements in sorted order. You need to call its [`Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to sort them (after you have completed populating it).
- You should implement `IComparable<T>` (in addition to `IComparable`) for performance.
- Set the breakpoint on `CompareTo`, not `Equals`. Sorting needs to determine the *order* of the elements, not their equality.